# Converting ANSI to UTF8 with Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, ansi

I have a Ruby script that generates an ANSI file.

I want to convert the file to UTF8.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is between ascii range 0 to 0x7F, its valid UTF8, so you don't need to do anything.

Or, if there is characters above 0x7F, you could use Iconv

```
text=Iconv.iconv('UTF-8', 'ascii',text)
```

Comment: I solution my problem.
My code is:
text=Iconv.iconv('UTF-8', 'gb2312',text)

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know your encoding was 'gb2312', so I put 'ascii' as example. You should have asked gb2312 to UTF8 in question. but anyway, glad to know its works.

Comment: Iconv has been deprecated in 1.9.3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148762/iconv-deprecation-warning-with-ruby-1-9-3 Try String#encode instead.

Answer (score 1):

The [8-bit Unicode Transformation Format (UTF-8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) was designed to be backwards compatible with the [American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Therefore, by definition, any valid ASCII sequence is also a valid UTF-8 sequence. For more information, read the [UTF FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) and [Unicode FAQ](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Any ASCII file is a valid UTF8 file, going by your Q's title, so no conversion is needed.  I don't know what a UIF8 file is, going by your Q's text, so different from its title.