# Force strings to UTF-8 from any encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, character-encoding

In my rails app I'm working with RSS feeds from all around the world, and some feeds have links that are not in UTF-8.  The original feed links are out of my control, and in order to use them in other parts of the app, they need to be in UTF-8.

How can I detect encoding and convert to UTF-8?

Comment: To detect an encoding, you need to parse the accompanying meta information of the documents, i.e. HTTP headers or `<meta>` tags.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Ruby 1.9

"Forcing" an encoding is easy, however it won't convert the characters just change the encoding:

```
str = str.force_encoding('UTF-8')

str.encoding.name # => 'UTF-8'
```

If you want to perform a conversion, use `encode`:

```
begin
  str.encode("UTF-8")
rescue Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
  # ...
end
```

I would definitely read the following post for more information:
http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings/ruby-19s-string

Comment: Doesn't work: 
whois = whois.force_encoding("UTF-8") \n whois.encoding.name
=> "UTF-8" \n whois.scan(/role:\s+(.+)/i) -- Throws: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Comment: As stated, force_encoding does not convert the characters and certainly cannot magically interpret invalid UTF-8 byte sequences.

Comment: Current syntax for Ruby 2.2.0 and above is:    ```str.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)```  [Encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Encoding.html)

Answer (score 42):

This will ensure you have the correct encoding and won't error out because it replaces any invalid or undefined character with a blank string.

This will ensure no matter what, that you have a valid UTF-8 string

```
str.encode(Encoding.find('UTF-8'), {invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ''})
```

For Ruby 3.0+:

```
str.encode(Encoding.find('UTF-8'), invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

Comment: This will raise `no implicit conversion of Hash into String` on modern ruby (probably after 3.0)

Use 

`str.encode(Encoding.find('UTF-8'), invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')`

Comment: thx i have this problem, your solution solve problem with ruby 3+ ;)

Answer (score 5):

Only this solution worked for me:

```
string.encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

Note the **binary** argument.

Answer (score 4):

[Iconv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/Iconv.html#method-c-iconv)

```
require 'iconv'
i = Iconv.new('UTF-8','LATIN1')
a_with_hat = i.iconv("\xc2")
```

Summary: the iconv gem does all the work of converting encodings. Make sure it's installed with:

```
gem install iconv
```

Now, you need to know what encoding your string is currently in as Ruby 1.8 treats Strings as an array of bytes (with no intrinsic encoding.) For example, say your string was in latin1 and you wanted to convert it to utf-8

```
require 'iconv'

string_in_utf8_encoding = Iconv.conv("UTF8", "LATIN1", string_in_latin1_encoding)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case the source data is inconsistent and I don't really have a reliable way to preempt encodings

Comment: Iconv should not be used anymore. (deprecated) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148762/iconv-deprecation-warning-with-ruby-1-9-3