# how to force UTF-8 in rails with html form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

how to force the rails form to accept utf headers
code:

```
str += '<form id=\"uploadformWebkit\" class=\"webkitUploadForm\"action=\"<%=APP_CONFIG[:ssl_url]%>/docs/upload_folder\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\">';
```

how to force utf-8 here?

Comment: 1.) Within Form helper tag...

  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1" method="post">

2.) read this for @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947910/force-strings-to-utf-8-from-any-encoding

Answer (score 1):

I use `simple_form`. I believe thats the default `Content-Type` if you have not tampered with the default settings during setup.

[image]

Also you will see additional `utf8 parameter` that gets posted along with other params:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.) Within Form helper tag...

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1" method="post">
```

2.) read this for @ [Force strings to UTF-8 from any encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947910/force-strings-to-utf-8-from-any-encoding)

Comment: in rails form this can be possible.
but html form
LIKE
str += '<form id=\"uploadformWebkit\" class=\"webkitUploadForm\"action=\"<%=APP_CONFIG[:ssl_url]%>/docs/upload_folder\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\">';